# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS - Wordpress error, cant find a reason

Tags: wordpress, cookies

I wanted to change domain of my site [kasyna.uk](https://kasyna.uk).

So, Hostinger have option to copy site to new domain which is spinyzarejestracje.pl. I used it and I have problems now. Last 2 days everything was right and site worked. Now I have problem with too many redirects. I cant even login to admin panel.

Hostinger gave me link to site "what to do in case of" and I did all things from list and site it still down. I also did search all similar cases here in Stackoverflow but none was helpful enough to make my site working. I did block all plugins but nothing changed.

Comment: Both sites load fine on my end so this is likely a DNS issue. Try to run `ipconfig /flushdns` in CMD and open the sites in a different browser. If it is confirmed to be a DNS propagation issue, it will resolve itself within a few days.